# is there a way to iterate through a string by incrementing the char through string slicing?

Tags: string, python-3.x, increment, slice

For example I want to increment the variable b by one so that the loop now checks for the second character in the string. In this case, the character "o". b +1 is what I want to achieve.

```
a = 'Goodbye'
b = 'Good'
c = ''

for letter in a:
    if letter == b[0]:
        c += letter
        #b [+1]
        print(c)
    else:
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the second character with `b[1]`, if you need to progressively increment into b, then use `b[i]` and increment `i` as needed.